# Qt - dynamically access elements

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a number of label-elements in my UI which I want to access dynamically from a `foreach()`. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(const QString &str, patternSlices) {
   i++;       
   ui->step_(i)->setPixmap(activeStep.scaled(100,100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));           
}
```

I'm searching all the time, but can't figure it out how to do that in C++/Qt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use findChild for search your labels:

```
foreach(const QString &str, patternSlices) {
   i++;       
   // suppose that your label has name label1...labelN
   QString labelName = QString("label%1").arg(i);
   QLabel* label = findChild<QLabel*>(labelName);
   if( label )
      label->setPixmap(activeStep.scaled(100,100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));           
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! :) I already had a look on findChildren() but I could not figure out how it works in my foreach() .. thank you a lot!! :)